# iOS & GIT Broken Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, git, storyboard

I've got a big problem with my iOS Project, after using the standard Source Control feature for BitBucket.

The last time I committed some changes to the repository my storyboards had all the views and constraint as i left them. The commit did not include changes to storyboard.

Now I opened my project, some UIViewControllers have all the views uninstalled, or some have the views at the correct position but all the constraint are broken.

What should i do ? I've reset all my changes, and no matter what commit I revert to, the Storyboard is in the same broken state.

**EDIT**

The problems seems to be with the storyboard it self, and does not involve GIT. In the storyboard, all the constraints have been uninstalled (but present), so the views have moved almost randomly on the screen. Also some views were uninstalled from the view controller.

**SOLUTION**

I reinstalled all of the views and constraints that were disabled. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

When a conflict happens I close Xcode and open the storyboard in Vim (or any other editor).

At heart, a storyboard is a big XML file with tags that Xcode maintains for you. Therefore, when you have a conflict, you will have the standard

```
<<<<<<
first storyboard lines
======
second storyboard lines
>>>>>>
```

structure.

When you are done with selecting the lines of the storyboard you want to keep (they're actually relatively readable), just `git add` the Storyboard file to mark the conflict as resolved as you would any other file, commit and profit.

Maybe you could also use `git blame` on the source code view of the Storyboard file to help you track down when exactly it broke, and hence why reverting doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Thank you for answering, but i don't have any workings in the source code of the leaderboard. I now think that git is not responsible, but Xcode is in fact the culprit.

Comment: What we do to reduce this type of issue (I know of course that it is a bit late to talk "preemptive measures", but it might help in the future) is to maintain smaller storyboards connected through storyboard reference segues.

Answer (score 0):

When you open the storyboard file as source code you will probably see the warnings due to the merge.

[image: Storyboard source]

Comment: Thank you for answering, but i don't have any workings in the source code of the leaderboard. I now think that git is not responsible, but Xcode is in fact the culprit.

Comment: Is it possible to post an image of the actual problem? It seems im not understanding your question completely.

Comment: All of my constrains are no longer installed (are present but not installed), so the views present have shifted almost randomly on the ViewController view. Some views have also been uninstalled from the ViewController.

Comment: Did you check if the if the constraints in the [storyboard builder are installed](https://postimg.org/image/i41v8yhif/)?

Comment: Somehow the constraints were uninstalled. I've begun to reinstall the constraints and update the frames of the views. I would very much like to know why did xcode break my storyboard...

Comment: I have no idea! But luckily you found a solution.